# Mouse position on the highchart not working on inverted

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Mouse coordinates are not translated properly with `chart.pointer.normalize()`. Maybe because zoom is enabled `zoomType: "y"` and `inverted: true` ? When zoom is applied starting offset seams to be added to wrong axis.

Here is the code showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/u3uj0fsq/1/

```js
$(function () {

function toHHMMSS(seconds) {
 // var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
 var sec_num = parseFloat(seconds);
 var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
 var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
 var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
 seconds = + seconds.toFixed(2);

 if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
 if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
 if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
 return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}

$('#container').mousemove(function(e){  
 var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
 e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
    $("#X").text(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft);
    $("#Y").text(e.chartY - chart.plotTop);
    var x = chart.xAxis[0].toValue(e.chartX);
    var y = chart.yAxis[0].toValue(e.chartY);
    $("#x-value").text(x + " " + toHHMMSS(x));
    $("#y-value").text(y + " " + toHHMMSS(y));
    $("#is-inside").text(chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop));
});


 Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
   type: 'columnrange',
   zoomType: "y",
   inverted: true
  },

  title: {
   text: 'Streams in recording'
  },

  subtitle: {
   text: '6588'
  },

  xAxis: {
   crosshair: {
    snap: true
   },

   categories: ['6588_webcam_43787at1482727133521', '6588_audio_43787at1482727132333', '6588_audio_43787at1482727150244', '6588_webcam_43787at1482727150594', '6588_audio_43786at1482727218838', '6588_webcam_43786at1482727219614', '6588_audio_43787at1482727232526', '6588_webcam_43787at1482727234960', '6588_audio_43787at1482727553896', '6588_webcam_43787at1482727652496', '6588_audio_43787at1482727750354', '6588_webcam_43787at1482727750367', '6588_webcam_43786at1482727971901', '6588_audio_43786at1482728032177', '6588_webcam_43787at1482728090987', '6588_audio_43787at1482728200896', '6588_audio_43787at1482728249272', '6588_webcam_43787at1482728249907', '6588_audio_43787at1482728328460', '6588_webcam_43787at1482728329288']
  },

  yAxis: {
   labels: {
    formatter: function () {
     return toHHMMSS(this.value) + " " + this.value;
    }
   },
   crosshair: {
    snap: false
   },
   title: {
    text: 'Time in seconds'
   }
  },

  tooltip: {
   valueSuffix: 'sec'
  },

  plotOptions: {
   columnrange: {
    dataLabels: {
     enabled: true,
     formatter: function () {
      return toHHMMSS(this.y) + ' sec';
     }
    }
   }
  },

  legend: {
   enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
   name: 'streams',
   data: [
{low:0.0, high:18.424, color: 'red'},
{low:1.58141918945, high:11.8814191895, color: 'red'},
{low:17.2593955078, high:20.3193955078, color: 'red'},
{low:26.3823586426, high:27.7133586426, color: 'red'},
{low:84.1229912109, high:887.882991211, color: 'blue'},
{low:85.8669787598, high:841.54397876, color: 'blue'},
{low:97.789045166, high:406.329045166, color: 'red'},
{low:101.676151611, high:374.801151611, color: 'red'},
{low:419.217322021, high:587.077322021, color: 'red'},
{low:521.401963135, high:587.180963135, color: 'red'},
{low:615.656143311, high:1053.87614331, color: 'red'},
{low:616.935256104, high:944.507256104, color: 'red'},
{low:838.497241699, high:1273.2172417, color: 'blue'},
{low:897.463297607, high:1273.20329761, color: 'blue'},
{low:960.277749023, high:1091.14674902, color: 'red'},
{low:1066.10784277, high:1089.38784277, color: 'red'},
{low:1115.09817798, high:1179.23817798, color: 'red'},
{low:1119.00694995, high:1177.86994995, color: 'red'},
{low:1193.76335791, high:1274.78335791, color: 'red'},
{low:1196.04498315, high:1274.82198315, color: 'red'},
   ]
  }]

 });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

 <div>X-Coordinate: <span id='X'>0</span></div>
 <div>Y-Coordinate: <span id='Y'>0</span></div>
 <div>X value: <span id='x-value'>0</span></div>
 <div>Y value: <span id='y-value'>0</span></div>
 <div>Is inside plot: <span id='is-inside'>false</span></div>
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; min-height: 400px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Mouse coordinate translation is mentioned in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/YQ6Bt/

Comment: With an inverted chart, the axes are swapped. http://jsfiddle.net/YQ6Bt/25/ It works correctly if you also swap the translation methods - or maybe I am missing something different there?